# Lighting engine for a 2D SDL game

Tags: c++, grid, lighting

Can somebody help me to make grid lighting system like in terraria? Actually i've done that like lighting
which works with half tile_size tiles, but it breaks my renderer because of 48 600 of blocks render every frame. I read whole web to find the answer, check Terraria open source but it wasn't obviously. Find that creating Lightmap texture and render whole texture rect, but how to create beautiful Lightmap without 40 thousands of microtiles?

here is my version of light update

```
    SDL_SetRenderTarget(renderer,TextureTest);
i2 = std::min(i2, WINDOW_HEIGHT - 1);
j2 = std::min(j2, WINDOW_WIDTH - 1);
SDL_Rect rect;
for (int i = i1; i < i2; ++i) {
    for (int j = j1; j < j2; ++j) {
        if (tiles[i][j].lightkoef != 0) {
            int i3 = i * 2;
            int j3 = j * 2;
            light_tiles[i3][j3] = 255; //lup
            light_tiles[i3][j3 + 1] = 255; //ldo
            light_tiles[i3 + 1][j3] = 255; //rup
            light_tiles[i3 + 1][j3 + 1] = 255; //rdo
            int tmp_i = i3;
            int tmp_j = j3;
            int step = 255 / (tiles[i][j].lightkoef + 1);
            while ((light_tiles[tmp_i][tmp_j] > 0) and
                   (tmp_i > (std::max(0, i3 - tiles[i][j].lightkoef)) and (tmp_j > j3 - tiles[i][j].lightkoef))) {
                int tmp_up = tmp_i - 1;
                int tmp_left = tmp_j - 1;
                while (tmp_up >= 0 and light_tiles[tmp_up + 1][tmp_j] > 0) {
                    if ((light_tiles[tmp_up + 1][tmp_j] - step > 0 ? light_tiles[tmp_up + 1][tmp_j] - step : 0) <=
                        light_tiles[tmp_up][tmp_j])
                        break;
                    light_tiles[tmp_up][tmp_j] =
                            light_tiles[tmp_up + 1][tmp_j] - step > 0 ? light_tiles[tmp_up + 1][tmp_j] - step : 0;
                    rect = {x_render + (tmp_j - j3) * TILE_SIZE / 2, y_render + (i - i3) * TILE_SIZE / 2,
                            TILE_SIZE / 2, TILE_SIZE / 2};
                    SDL_SetRenderDrawBlendMode(renderer, SDL_BLENDMODE_BLEND);
                    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0, 0, 0, 255 - light_tiles[tmp_up][tmp_left]);
                    SDL_RenderFillRect(renderer, &rect);
                    SDL_SetRenderDrawBlendMode(renderer, SDL_BLENDMODE_NONE);
                    tmp_up -= 1;
                }
                while (tmp_left >= 0 and light_tiles[tmp_i][tmp_left + 1] > 0) {
                    if ((light_tiles[tmp_i][tmp_left + 1] - step > 0 ? light_tiles[tmp_i][tmp_left + 1] - step
                                                                     : 0) <= light_tiles[tmp_i][tmp_left])
                        break;
                    light_tiles[tmp_i][tmp_left] =
                            light_tiles[tmp_i][tmp_left + 1] - step > 0 ? light_tiles[tmp_i][tmp_left + 1] - step
                                                                        : 0;
                    rect = {x_render + (tmp_left - j3) * TILE_SIZE / 2, y_render + (tmp_i - i3) * TILE_SIZE / 2,
                            TILE_SIZE / 2, TILE_SIZE / 2};
                    SDL_SetRenderDrawBlendMode(renderer, SDL_BLENDMODE_BLEND);
                    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0, 0, 0, 255 - light_tiles[tmp_i][tmp_left]);
                    SDL_RenderFillRect(renderer, &rect);
                    SDL_SetRenderDrawBlendMode(renderer, SDL_BLENDMODE_NONE);
                    tmp_left -= 1;
                }
                tmp_i -= 1;
                tmp_j -= 1;
                if ((light_tiles[tmp_i + 1][tmp_j + 1] - 2 * step > 0 ? light_tiles[tmp_i + 1][tmp_j + 1] - 2 * step
                                                                      : 0) <= light_tiles[tmp_i][tmp_j])
                    break;
                light_tiles[tmp_i][tmp_j] =
                        light_tiles[tmp_i + 1][tmp_j + 1] - 2 * step > 0 ? light_tiles[tmp_i + 1][tmp_j + 1] -
                                                                           2 * step : 0;
                rect = {x_render + (tmp_j - j3) * TILE_SIZE / 2, y_render + (tmp_i - i3) * TILE_SIZE / 2,
                        TILE_SIZE / 2, TILE_SIZE / 2};
                SDL_SetRenderDrawBlendMode(renderer, SDL_BLENDMODE_BLEND);
                SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0, 0, 0, 255 - light_tiles[tmp_i][tmp_j]);
                SDL_RenderFillRect(renderer, &rect);
                SDL_SetRenderDrawBlendMode(renderer, SDL_BLENDMODE_NONE);
            }

            tmp_i = i3;
            tmp_j = j3 + 1;
           step = 255/tiles[i][j].lightkoef;
            while ((light_tiles[tmp_i][tmp_j] > 0) and (tmp_i > (std::max(0, i3 - tiles[i][j].lightkoef)) and
                                                        (tmp_j > j3 + 1 - tiles[i][j].lightkoef))) {
                int tmp_up = tmp_i - 1;
                int tmp_right = tmp_j + 1;
                while (tmp_up >= 0 and light_tiles[tmp_up + 1][tmp_j] > 0) {
                    if ((light_tiles[tmp_up + 1][tmp_j] - step > 0 ? light_tiles[tmp_up + 1][tmp_j] - step : 0) <=
                        light_tiles[tmp_up][tmp_j])
                        break;
                    light_tiles[tmp_up][tmp_j] =
                            light_tiles[tmp_up + 1][tmp_j] - step > 0 ? light_tiles[tmp_up + 1][tmp_j] - step : 0;
                    rect = {x_render + (tmp_j - j3) * TILE_SIZE / 2, y_render + (tmp_up - i3) * TILE_SIZE / 2,
                            TILE_SIZE / 2, TILE_SIZE / 2};
                    SDL_SetRenderDrawBlendMode(renderer, SDL_BLENDMODE_BLEND);
                    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0, 0, 0, 255 - light_tiles[tmp_up][tmp_j]);
                    SDL_RenderFillRect(renderer, &rect);
                    SDL_SetRenderDrawBlendMode(renderer, SDL_BLENDMODE_NONE);
                    tmp_up -= 1;
                }
                while (tmp_right >= 0 and light_tiles[tmp_i][tmp_right - 1] > 0) {
                    if ((light_tiles[tmp_i][tmp_right - 1] - step > 0 ? light_tiles[tmp_i][tmp_right - 1] - step
                                                                      : 0) <= light_tiles[tmp_i][tmp_right])
                        break;
                    light_tiles[tmp_i][tmp_right] = (light_tiles[tmp_i][tmp_right - 1] - step > 0 ?
                                                     light_tiles[tmp_i][tmp_right - 1] - step : 0);
                    rect = {x_render + (tmp_right - j3) * TILE_SIZE / 2, y_render + (tmp_i - i3) * TILE_SIZE / 2,
                            TILE_SIZE / 2, TILE_SIZE / 2};
                    SDL_SetRenderDrawBlendMode(renderer, SDL_BLENDMODE_BLEND);
                    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0, 0, 0, 255 - light_tiles[tmp_i][tmp_right]);
                    SDL_RenderFillRect(renderer, &rect);
                    SDL_SetRenderDrawBlendMode(renderer, SDL_BLENDMODE_NONE);
                    tmp_right += 1;
                }
                tmp_i -= 1;
                tmp_j += 1;
                if ((light_tiles[tmp_i + 1][tmp_j - 1] - 2 * step > 0 ? light_tiles[tmp_i + 1][tmp_j - 1] - 2 * step
                                                                      : 0) <= light_tiles[tmp_i][tmp_j])
                    break;
                light_tiles[tmp_i][tmp_j] =
                        light_tiles[tmp_i + 1][tmp_j - 1] - 2 * step > 0 ? light_tiles[tmp_i + 1][tmp_j - 1] -
                                                                           2 * step : 0;
                rect = {x_render + (tmp_j - j3) * TILE_SIZE / 2, y_render + (tmp_i - i3) * TILE_SIZE / 2,
                        TILE_SIZE / 2, TILE_SIZE / 2};
                SDL_SetRenderDrawBlendMode(renderer, SDL_BLENDMODE_BLEND);
                SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0, 0, 0, 255 - light_tiles[tmp_i][tmp_j]);
                SDL_RenderFillRect(renderer, &rect);
                SDL_SetRenderDrawBlendMode(renderer, SDL_BLENDMODE_NONE);
            }

            tmp_i = i3 + 1;
            tmp_j = j3 + 1;
            while ((light_tiles[tmp_i][tmp_j] > 0) and (tmp_i > i3 + 1 - tiles[i][j].lightkoef) and
                   (tmp_j > j3 + 1 - tiles[i][j].lightkoef)) {
                int tmp_up = tmp_i + 1;
                int tmp_right = tmp_j + 1;
                while (tmp_up >= 0 and light_tiles[tmp_up - 1][tmp_j] > 0) {
                    if ((light_tiles[tmp_up - 1][tmp_j] - step > 0 ? light_tiles[tmp_up - 1][tmp_j] - step : 0) <=
                        light_tiles[tmp_up][tmp_j])
                        break;
                    light_tiles[tmp_up][tmp_j] =
                            light_tiles[tmp_up - 1][tmp_j] - step > 0 ? light_tiles[tmp_up - 1][tmp_j] - step : 0;
                    rect = {x_render + (tmp_j - j3) * TILE_SIZE / 2, y_render + (tmp_up - i3) * TILE_SIZE / 2,
                            TILE_SIZE / 2, TILE_SIZE / 2};
                    SDL_SetRenderDrawBlendMode(renderer, SDL_BLENDMODE_BLEND);
                    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0, 0, 0, 255 - light_tiles[tmp_up][tmp_j]);
                    SDL_RenderFillRect(renderer, &rect);
                    SDL_SetRenderDrawBlendMode(renderer, SDL_BLENDMODE_NONE);
                    tmp_up += 1;
                }
                while (tmp_right >= 0 and light_tiles[tmp_i][tmp_right - 1] > 0) {
                    if ((light_tiles[tmp_i][tmp_right - 1] - step > 0 ? light_tiles[tmp_i][tmp_right - 1] - step
                                                                      : 0) <= light_tiles[tmp_i][tmp_right])
                        break;
                    light_tiles[tmp_i][tmp_right] = (light_tiles[tmp_i][tmp_right - 1] - step > 0 ?
                                                     light_tiles[tmp_i][tmp_right - 1] - step : 0);
                    rect = {x_render + (tmp_right - j3) * TILE_SIZE / 2, y_render + (tmp_i - i3) * TILE_SIZE / 2,
                            TILE_SIZE / 2, TILE_SIZE / 2};
                    SDL_SetRenderDrawBlendMode(renderer, SDL_BLENDMODE_BLEND);
                    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0, 0, 0, 255 - light_tiles[tmp_i][tmp_right]);
                    SDL_RenderFillRect(renderer, &rect);
                    SDL_SetRenderDrawBlendMode(renderer, SDL_BLENDMODE_NONE);
                    tmp_right += 1;
                }
                tmp_i += 1;
                tmp_j += 1;
                if ((light_tiles[tmp_i - 1][tmp_j - 1] - 2 * step > 0 ? light_tiles[tmp_i - 1][tmp_j - 1] - 2 * step
                                                                      : 0) <= light_tiles[tmp_i][tmp_j])
                    break;
                light_tiles[tmp_i][tmp_j] =
                        light_tiles[tmp_i - 1][tmp_j - 1] - 2 * step > 0 ? light_tiles[tmp_i - 1][tmp_j - 1] -
                                                                           2 * step : 0;
                rect = {x_render + (tmp_j - j3) * TILE_SIZE / 2, y_render + (tmp_i - i3) * TILE_SIZE / 2,
                        TILE_SIZE / 2, TILE_SIZE / 2};
                SDL_SetRenderDrawBlendMode(renderer, SDL_BLENDMODE_BLEND);
                SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0, 0, 0, 255 - light_tiles[tmp_i][tmp_j]);
                SDL_RenderFillRect(renderer, &rect);
                SDL_SetRenderDrawBlendMode(renderer, SDL_BLENDMODE_NONE);
            }

            tmp_i = i3 + 1;
            tmp_j = j3;
            while ((light_tiles[tmp_i][tmp_j] > 0) and (tmp_i > i3 + 1 - tiles[i][j].lightkoef) and
                   (tmp_j > j3 - tiles[i][j].lightkoef)) {
                int tmp_down = tmp_i + 1;
                int tmp_left = tmp_j - 1;
                while (tmp_down >= 0 and light_tiles[tmp_down - 1][tmp_j] > 0) {
                    if ((light_tiles[tmp_down - 1][tmp_j] - step > 0 ? light_tiles[tmp_down - 1][tmp_j] - step
                                                                     : 0) <= light_tiles[tmp_down][tmp_j])
                        break;
                    light_tiles[tmp_down][tmp_j] =
                            light_tiles[tmp_down - 1][tmp_j] - step > 0 ? light_tiles[tmp_down - 1][tmp_j] - step
                                                                        : 0;
                    rect = {x_render + (tmp_j - j3) * TILE_SIZE / 2, y_render + (tmp_down - i3) * TILE_SIZE / 2,
                            TILE_SIZE / 2, TILE_SIZE / 2};
                    SDL_SetRenderDrawBlendMode(renderer, SDL_BLENDMODE_BLEND);
                    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0, 0, 0, 255 - light_tiles[tmp_down][tmp_j]);
                    SDL_RenderFillRect(renderer, &rect);
                    SDL_SetRenderDrawBlendMode(renderer, SDL_BLENDMODE_NONE);
                    tmp_down += 1;
                }
                while (tmp_left >= 0 and light_tiles[tmp_i][tmp_left + 1] > 0) {
                    if ((light_tiles[tmp_i][tmp_left + 1] - step > 0 ? light_tiles[tmp_i][tmp_left + 1] - step
                                                                     : 0) <= light_tiles[tmp_i][tmp_left])
                        break;
                    light_tiles[tmp_i][tmp_left] = (light_tiles[tmp_i][tmp_left + 1] - step > 0 ?
                                                    light_tiles[tmp_i][tmp_left + 1] - step : 0);
                    rect = {x_render + (tmp_left - j3) * TILE_SIZE / 2, y_render + (tmp_i - i3) * TILE_SIZE / 2,
                            TILE_SIZE / 2, TILE_SIZE / 2};
                    SDL_SetRenderDrawBlendMode(renderer, SDL_BLENDMODE_BLEND);
                    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0, 0, 0, 255 - light_tiles[tmp_i][tmp_left]);
                    SDL_RenderFillRect(renderer, &rect);
                    SDL_SetRenderDrawBlendMode(renderer, SDL_BLENDMODE_NONE);
                    tmp_left -= 1;
                }
                tmp_i += 1;
                tmp_j -= 1;
                if ((light_tiles[tmp_i - 1][tmp_j + 1] - 2 * step > 0 ? light_tiles[tmp_i - 1][tmp_j + 1] - 2 * step
                                                                      : 0) <= light_tiles[tmp_i][tmp_j])
                    break;
                light_tiles[tmp_i][tmp_j] =
                        light_tiles[tmp_i - 1][tmp_j + 1] - 2 * step > 0 ? light_tiles[tmp_i - 1][tmp_j + 1] -
                                                                           2 * step : 0;
                rect = {x_render + (tmp_j - j3) * TILE_SIZE / 2, y_render + (tmp_i - i3) * TILE_SIZE / 2,
                        TILE_SIZE / 2, TILE_SIZE / 2};
                SDL_SetRenderDrawBlendMode(renderer, SDL_BLENDMODE_BLEND);
                SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0, 0, 0, 255 - light_tiles[tmp_i][tmp_j]);
                SDL_RenderFillRect(renderer, &rect);
                SDL_SetRenderDrawBlendMode(renderer, SDL_BLENDMODE_NONE);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[works like that but eats all fps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/59pcJ.png)

Comment: You have tagged C++, what have you tried to code so far or what research have you done already for your use case in C++?

Comment: If you are asking how to make lighting like Terraria the question is too broad. If you already tried it and it didn't work and you're asking how to fix it, it's not clear what you tried and why it didn't work.

Comment: it works but too slowly and eats 140 fps, I have attached the code

Comment: Seems like it does a lot of work and draws a lot of rectangles. What happened to lightmap textures?

Comment: yeap that is the problem of many rects drawing, actually calculation are fast but renderer does a huge work to draw all of them. I thought that if i target the light texture and draw whole window rect with texture it will be more profit but actually i draw on texture same rects and got no profit